# Template implemetion error

Tags: magento-1.7, blocks, template, wordpress, head

I tried for a hours, but i can't find out. i created static block on header, and i tried to call the header out side of magento. I'm able to connect to magento, but the header is not showed. My code is below

```
$layout = Mage::getModel('core/layout');

$head = $layout->getBlock('head');
$head->setTemplate('page/html/head.phtml');

$post = get_post( $post );
$metaTitle = pods_field('video', $post->ID, 'meta_title', true);
$metaDescription = pods_field('video', $post->ID, 'meta_description', true);

$head->setTitleWp($metaTitle);
$head->setMetaDescription($metaDescription);

echo $head->toHtml();
```

And i got the below error.

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplate() on a non-object in
```

Comment: Any one there to help me out of this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All are quite with other work and i found the solution.

```
$layout = Mage::getModel('core/layout');
$layout->getUpdate()->load('default');
$layout->generateXml()->generateBlocks();

$head = $layout->getBlock('head');
$head->setTemplate('page/html/head.phtml');

$post = get_post( $post );
$metaTitle = pods_field('video', $post->ID, 'meta_title', true);
$metaDescription = pods_field('video', $post->ID, 'meta_description', true);

$head->setTitleWp($metaTitle);
$head->setMetaDescription($metaDescription);

echo $head->toHtml();
```

[References Link](https://tagmycode.com/snippet/2183/load-get-a-block-outside-of-magento-routing-for-external-use#.WAYPTLUvAl_)